# wrong status line: "TTP/1.1 302 Found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing an HTTP request from a Rails action like so:

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController 
  def test
    _uri = 'http://v.youku.com/player/getPlayList/VideoIDS/XNjQyNjg3ODg0_ev_5'
    _html_response = nil
    open(_uri) do |http|
      _html_response = http.read
    end
    render text: _html_response
  end
end
```

But I get the error:

> wrong status line: "TTP/1.1 302 Found"

But I used the same code in a simple Ruby file and I got the response without any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `open` method?

Comment: Thanks,the `open` method is from `require "open-uri"`.

Comment: Are you trying to read content from a given url ?

Comment: thanks,I find the reason,that's because my ubuntu vm is forbided to visit this site.sheet!

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,I find the reason,that's because my ubuntu vm is forbided to visit this site.sheet!